# How to share (config.vm.synced_folder), directories between Windows 10 and CentOS7 Virtual Machine created using Vagrant and VirtualBox

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, centos-7, vagrant, shared-folders

I'm trying to create a VM CentOS7 using Vagrant (2.2.3) and Virtual Box (6.0.4), on Windows 10 using the following Vagrant file

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/centos-7" 
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.56.3"

  config.vm.synced_folder "D://SharedWithVM//CentOS7-Work", "/media/sf_CentOS7-Work", type: "virtualbox"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.name = "Test"
   end
   config.vm.provision "shell", path: "./scripts/InstallGuestAdditions.sh"
end
```

and the `InstallGuestAdditions.sh` shell script is the follow ..

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -C - -O http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.4/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.0.4.iso
sudo mkdir /media/VBoxGuestAdditions
sudo mount -o loop,ro VBoxGuestAdditions_6.0.4.iso /media/VBoxGuestAdditions
sudo sh /media/VBoxGuestAdditions/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
rm VBoxGuestAdditions_6.0.4.iso
sudo umount /media/VBoxGuestAdditions
sudo rmdir /media/VBoxGuestAdditions
```

All works fine and the CentOS7 VM is created.

If I check the machine properties about shared directories I can see this

[image]

So I'm quite surprised  about this path `\\?\D:\SharedWithVM\CentOS7-Work`.

How should I change my  Vagrantfile to obtain a right path?

I've tried to connect at my CentOS 7 VM using `vagrant ssh` command and all works. Also the command `cd /media/sf_CentOS7-Work` works fine but no file or directory can be listed or shared between the two systems.

Here you're a snapshot on my VM CentOS7

[image]

I've tried to create files or directories in Windows 10 and also in CentOS7 VM.

Any suggestion or example will be appreciated.

Comment: The "\\?\" prefix to a path is to allow [long path names](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-filenames.html) and is the result of some VirtualBox bug reports like [this one](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/4815). This is by design and should work. Is the CentOS user added to the `vboxsf` group and the rights are ok on the folder sf_CentOS7-Work? See if [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/460432/17660) helps.

Comment: I'm quite a newbie on these stuffs, so sorry but .... how may I check if the CentOS user added to the vboxsf group? Anyway I'll see the link you've given me

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully do this in my Virtualbox image earlier; hopefully it will work for you too.

Directions: Inside of your virtual machine:

1. Create a directory (e.g. `mkdir -p /mnt/share`)
2. Mount the shared folder to the directory you just created, where "shared_folder" is the name of the shared folder you set up from Settings earlier (e.g. `mount -t vboxsf shared_folder /mnt/share`)

You should now be able to access files from your equivalent `/mnt/share` directory

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

config.vm.synced_folder "C:\Users\syed\Pvagrant2\data\testplay", "/vagrant", type: 'rsync'

vagant up --provison

==> default: Rsyncing folder: /cygdrive/c/Users/syed/Pvagrant2/data/testplay/ => /vagrant
==> default: Running provisioner: ansible_local...
default: Running ansible-playbook...

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************